# How to create a bash script that will take optional arguments and then pass these optional arguments to a java class

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm kinda new to this forum so please bear with me for this simple question.

I am new to scripting. I need to create a script that will check the optional parameters when it is run. For example:

```
./g -input filename -output filename -option run|stop|break
```

After I read the options given, I need to pass these parameters to a java class where it will be run and processed.

I read about `getopt` or `getopts` but I am having a hard time understanding it.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a sample code for bash arg processing (there could be other, maybe better approaches).

As you can see the core of this solution is the `$#` bash variable for argument number and the `shift` bash command for clearing one argument at the time. If you `echo $1` use `shift` end `echo $1` again you will get the next argument.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Args: $@ ($#)"

while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    echo "All arg count: $#"
    echo "I act arg: " $1
    case $1 in
        -option)
            echo "This is the option: $2"
            shift 2
            ;;
        -verbose)
            echo "I am doing verbose output!"
            set -x
            shift
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Unknown arg: " $1
            shift
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Output:

```
$ /tmp/test.sh as asd asdf asdf5 -option foo asd -verbose -asd 755
Args: as asd asdf asdf5 -option foo asd -verbose -asd 755 (10)
All arg count: 10
I act arg:  as
Unknown arg:  as
All arg count: 9
I act arg:  asd
Unknown arg:  asd
All arg count: 8
I act arg:  asdf
Unknown arg:  asdf
All arg count: 7
I act arg:  asdf5
Unknown arg:  asdf5
All arg count: 6
I act arg:  -option
This is the option: foo
All arg count: 4
I act arg:  asd
Unknown arg:  asd
All arg count: 3
I act arg:  -verbose
I am doing verbose output!
+ shift
+ '[' 2 -gt 0 ']'
+ echo 'All arg count: 2'
All arg count: 2
+ echo 'I act arg: ' -asd
I act arg:  -asd
+ case $1 in
+ echo 'Unknown arg: ' -asd
Unknown arg:  -asd
+ shift
+ '[' 1 -gt 0 ']'
+ echo 'All arg count: 1'
All arg count: 1
+ echo 'I act arg: ' 755
I act arg:  755
+ case $1 in
+ echo 'Unknown arg: ' 755
Unknown arg:  755
+ shift
+ '[' 0 -gt 0 ']'
```

If you look after these main commands I think you can write quite a simple script for the job. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that you are trying to use bash to deal with arguments?  Just pass the whole mess to the java main, then the java program can be run with or without a bash script and will be much more portable to other platforms in the future.

Take a look at Apache CLI (http://commons.apache.org/cli) for Java command line argument processing.

Comment: The requirement is I need a way to run the process in a console in Ubuntu which takes the arguments and then process these arguments in java code. All i can think of is use a script to do it as I have tried using a script before to run a java code but not with arguments. Also i think i can check the arguments first in the script before passing it to the java program.